# Does Amit Sahai's indistinguishability obfuscator enable Autonomous Virtual Corporations or "Agents"?

Tags: encryption, altcoin, cryptography, contracts, oracle

Given that an "Agent" [is described as](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts)

> Agents are autonomous programs that maintain their own wallet, which they use to buy server time. Money is obtained by the agent selling services. If demand exceeds supply the agents can spawn children that either survive or die depending on whether they can get enough business.

When combined with this [cryptographic breakthrough](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2014/02/cryptography-breakthrough/), it seems that [Virtual Corporations](http://btcgeek.com/dawn-of-autonomous-corporations/) and "Agents", which were purely theoretical, might now have the ability to exist and can encrypt a wallet's private key from a person who is running it.  The agent could then spend from it when pre-determined conditions are met (as verified from an [oracle](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts#Trust_minimization%3a_multiple_independent_oracles) of some type).

**Question**

Is it possible to use this technology, based in fully homomorphic encryption, or a variant thereof, to create an autonomous agent with it's own wallet?

What other bitcoin solutions can be made with this?